# Spring 3 question -- ModelAndView and Controller not being resolved

Tags: java, spring-3

I'm trying to learn Spring 3.  I have a class where I'm trying to do these two imports:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
```

Eclipse is telling me that neither import can be resolved, but I have org.spring
framework.web.servlet-sources-3.1.0.M1.jar in my classpath, and I have verified for a fact, by way of running it through jar -tf, that both of the above classes are in this jar.  Can anyone explain to me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-sources.jar`s usually just contain the original .java source files, not the compiled .class files. Find the version of the same jar without `-sources` in it's name and add that to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that jar has the classes you're looking for?  Take a look here http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html. I  have a feeling you need different jars.

Comment: I just tried the jars listed in this link, and it didn't work.